# How do I get data from all rows in a single column?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am a php noob and am having a hard time figuring out something that seems like it should be quite simple. My main goal here is to get ALL numbers found in column "number" and then list numbers 01-20 as long as they DON'T show up in the database.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$select = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `memfav`");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
    $number = $row['number'];
}
for($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) {
    if($i<>$number) {
        if($i<10) {
            echo "<option value=\"$i\">0$i</option>";   
        }
        else{
            echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
        }

    }
}
```

However, It's only not showing the latest entry. Am I completely missing something?

**ETA:** For anybody who is looking for something similar, I finally figured out a way to achieve this! (with the help from someone else)

```
$select = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `number` FROM `memfav`");
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select) ) {
$numbers[] = $row['number'];
}
for($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) {
if( !in_array($i, $numbers) ) {
    echo '<option value="$i">' . str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '</option>';
}
}
```

Comment: You mean if numbers like 14,15 are there in database, then the option should should show 1-13 and 16-20? This way?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to acheive

Comment: So far none of the proposed solutions has worked...

Comment: Then there's no need to run an extra loop. You could have written it within the query itself.

Answer (score 2):

You have placed your comparison logic outside of your `while` loop; As written, your code loops through your mysql results and sets `$number` to a new value for each row. This loop completes, leaving `$number` equal to the value from the last row returned. Then it checks the final value of `$number` against the values 1-20. To fix this, place the comparison logic inside the `while` loop.

Comment: I did that and what I got was two separate lists (1-20), the first not showing "1" and the second not showing "2". I want them all in the same list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$numbers = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    if ($i < 10) {
        $numbers[] = "0{$i}";
    } else {
        $numbers[] = "{$i}";
    }
}

$select = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM memfav");
$usedNumbers = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
    $usedNumbers[] = $row['number'];
}

$diff = array_diff($numbers, $usedNumbers);

foreach ($diff  as $key => $value) {
     echo "<option value=\"{$value}\">{$value}</option>";   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$select = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `memfav`");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
    $number = $row['number'];
    for($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) {
      if($i<>$number) {
        if($i<10) {
            echo "<option value=\"$i\">0$i</option>";   
        }
        else{
            echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
        }

      }
    }
}
```